# 'ID_GY' was not declared in this scope

Tags: android, c++, header

I am a complete code noob and I'm trying to implement a HAL (specifically the BMA222 Sensor) to my Android device.

When I try this code (BMA222.cpp):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <cutils/log.h>

#include "BMA222Sensor.h"

#define CONVERT                     (GRAVITY_EARTH / 256)
//#define CONVERT_GRAVITY_X           (CONVERT)
//#define CONVERT_GRAVITY_Y           (-1 * CONVERT)
//#define CONVERT_GRAVITY_Z           (-1 * CONVERT)
#define SENSOR_NAME                 "bma222"

/*****************************************************************************/

BMA222Sensor::BMA222Sensor()
    : SensorBase(NULL, SENSOR_NAME),
      mEnabled(0),
      mInputReader(4),
      mHasPendingEvent(false),
      mEnabledTime(0)
{
    mPendingEvent.version = sizeof(sensors_event_t);
    mPendingEvent.sensor = ID_GY;
    mPendingEvent.type = SENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER;
    memset(mPendingEvent.data, 0, sizeof(mPendingEvent.data));

    if (sensor_get_class_path() < 0)
        LOGD("Failed to get class path\n");
}

BMA222Sensor::~BMA222Sensor() {
    if (mEnabled) {
        enable(0, 0);
    }
}

int BMA222Sensor::enable(int32_t, int en) {
    int flags = en ? 1 : 0;
    char buf[2];
    int count = 0;;

    if (flags != mEnabled) {
            buf[1] = 0;
            if (flags) {
                buf[0] = '1';
                mEnabledTime = getTimestamp();
            } else {
                buf[0] = '0';
            }
        set_sysfs_input_attr(class_path, "enable", buf, 1);
            mEnabled = flags;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool BMA222Sensor::hasPendingEvents() const {
    return mHasPendingEvent;
}

int BMA222Sensor::setDelay(int32_t handle, int64_t delay_ns)
{
    char buf[80];
    int count = 0;;
    int64_t delay_ms = delay_ns / 1000000;

    count = sprintf(buf, "%lld", delay_ms);
    set_sysfs_input_attr(class_path, "delay", buf, count);

    return 0;
}

int BMA222Sensor::readEvents(sensors_event_t* data, int count)
{
    if (count < 1)
        return -EINVAL;

    if (mHasPendingEvent) {
        mHasPendingEvent = false;
        mPendingEvent.timestamp = getTimestamp();
        *data = mPendingEvent;
        return mEnabled ? 1 : 0;
    }

    ssize_t n = mInputReader.fill(data_fd);
    if (n < 0)
        return n;

    int numEventReceived = 0;
    input_event const* event;

    while (count && mInputReader.readEvent(&event)) {
        int type = event->type;
        if (type == EV_ABS) {
            float value = event->value;
            if (event->code == ABS_X) {
                //mPendingEvent.data[1] = value * CONVERT_GRAVITY_Y;
                mPendingEvent.data[0] = value * CONVERT;
            } else if (event->code == ABS_Y) {
                //mPendingEvent.data[0] = value * CONVERT_GRAVITY_X;
                mPendingEvent.data[1] = value * CONVERT;
            } else if (event->code == ABS_Z) {
                //mPendingEvent.data[2] = value * CONVERT_GRAVITY_Z;
                mPendingEvent.data[2] = value * CONVERT;
            }
        } else if (type == EV_SYN) {
            mPendingEvent.version = sizeof(sensors_event_t);
            mPendingEvent.sensor = ID_A;
            mPendingEvent.type = SENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER;
            mPendingEvent.timestamp = timevalToNano(event->time);
            *data++ = mPendingEvent;
            numEventReceived++;
            count--;
        } else {
            LOGE("BMA222Sensor: unknown event (type=%d, code=%d)",
                    type, event->code);
        }
        mInputReader.next();
    }

    return numEventReceived;
}

bool BMA222Sensor::isEnabled(int32_t handle) {
    return (0 != (mEnabled)) ? true : false;
}

int BMA222Sensor::sensor_get_class_path()
{
    char dirname[] = "/sys/class/input";
    char buf[256];
    int res;
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *de;
    int fd = -1;
    int found = 0;

    dir = opendir(dirname);
    if (dir == NULL)
        return -1;

    while((de = readdir(dir))) {
        if (strncmp(de->d_name, "input", strlen("input")) != 0) {
                continue;
        }

        sprintf(class_path, "%s/%s", dirname, de->d_name);
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s/name", class_path);

        fd = open(buf, O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0) {
                continue;
        }
        if ((res = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) < 0) {
                close(fd);
                continue;
        }
        buf[res - 1] = '\0';
        if (strcmp(buf, SENSOR_NAME) == 0) {
                found = 1;
                close(fd);
                break;
        }

        close(fd);
        fd = -1;
    }
    closedir(dir);

    if (found) {
        return 0;
    }else {
        *class_path = '\0';
        return -1;
    }
}

int BMA222Sensor:: set_sysfs_input_attr(char *class_path,
                const char *attr, char *value, int len)
{
    char path[256];
    int fd;

    if (class_path == NULL || *class_path == '\0'
            || attr == NULL || value == NULL || len < 1) {
        return -EINVAL;
    }
    snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", class_path, attr);
    path[sizeof(path) - 1] = '\0';
    fd = open(path, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
            return -errno;
    }
    if (write(fd, value, len) < 0) {
        close(fd);
        return -errno;
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

And this (BMA222Sensor.h):

```
#ifndef ANDROID_BMA222_SENSOR_H
#define ANDROID_BMA222_SENSOR_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include "sensors.h"
#include "SensorBase.h"
#include "InputEventReader.h"

/*****************************************************************************/

struct input_event;

class BMA222Sensor : public SensorBase {
    int mEnabled;
    InputEventCircularReader mInputReader;
    sensors_event_t mPendingEvent;
    bool mHasPendingEvent;
    char input_sysfs_path[PATH_MAX];
    int input_sysfs_path_len;
    int64_t mEnabledTime;

    char class_path[256];
    int sensor_get_class_path();
    int set_sysfs_input_attr(char *class_path,
                             const char *attr, char *value, int len);
public:
            BMA222Sensor();
    virtual ~BMA222Sensor();
    virtual int readEvents(sensors_event_t* data, int count);
    virtual bool hasPendingEvents() const;
    virtual int setDelay(int32_t handle, int64_t ns);
    virtual int enable(int32_t handle, int enabled);
    virtual bool isEnabled(int32_t handle);     //rockie
};

/*****************************************************************************/

#endif  // ANDROID_BMA222_SENSOR_H
```

I get this (shortened):

```
In constructor 'BMA222Sensor::BMA222Sensor()':
error: 'ID_GY' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [BMA222Sensor.o] Error 1
```

I don't understand where I'm going wrong, any help?

Comment: Well where do you think `ID_GY` is declared? It's declared nowhere in the code you have posted.

Comment: I tried to do `BMA222Sensor::BMA222Sensor(&ID_GY)` , but that's not how you do it huh? Sorry, I really am a complete noob here.

Comment: No, it isn't. Unfortunately I know nothing about android only C++. I would guess that ID_GY is a integer value that identifies the sensor. One way to define that would be to write `#define ID_GY 100` just after where you wrote `#define SENSOR_NAME ...`. The value of 100 is arbitrary, it might not matter too much what the actual value is, but I could easily be wrong about that.

Comment: Well, at least the error doesn't pop up anymore, thanks. How do I set this as the answer?

Comment: I have to convert it to one. I'm glad you're confident enough to accept it as an answer. I'm not sure I am!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I know nothing about android only C++. I would guess that ID_GY is a integer value that identifies the sensor. One way to define that would be to write

```
#define ID_GY 100
```

just after where you wrote

```
#define SENSOR_NAME "bma222"
```

The value of 100 is arbitrary, it might not matter too much what the actual value is, but I could easily be wrong about that.